# Will interrupting the script delete the progress in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently running a script in Jupyter Notebook which loops over a Dataframe and manipulates the data of the current row. As my Dataframe has thousands of rows and each loop takes a while to run, I am wondering whether it's safe to interrupt the script without losing all of my progress?

I am keeping track of rows that have already been processed so I could just start where I left off in the case that the manipulations on the Dataframe don't get lost. I don't want to take the risk of trying it out right now so advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are storing progress in external files, interrupting Jupyter will lose you data. I highly do not recommend on counting on the variables inside of Jupyter on being in some state if you are mid-way through a calculation, just save intermediate steps in files to track progress, chunking as you go.

Comment: The thing is that if the script stops running because of an error, the previous progress is still there, which is why I'm suspecting that it should behave similarly on a manual interruption, right? Of course, it will be gone once I fully quit out of the notebook - I get that.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like pandas is saving some of this in a cache possibly? Or again, the intermediate state of your variables have only been updated to a current value in your calculation. Why are you trying to interrupt the notebook in the first place? What is the actual issue here?

Comment: In the first place I'm just curious but also I would like to go to sleep and not have my laptop running all night :-)